# Why is the DocumentSaved event not firing for a web site solution?

Tags: events, visual-studio-sdk

I've been trying to get a simple visual studio add in working. I just want to run a function on a file when a document is saved, but for some reason the event is not firing for web site solutions. It works as expected on normal projects.

Here is my code so far:

```
    DocumentEvents docEvents;
    Events events;

    public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
    {
        _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
        _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;

        events = _applicationObject.Events;
        docEvents = events.DocumentEvents;

        docEvents.DocumentSaved += new _dispDocumentEvents_DocumentSavedEventHandler(docEvents_DocumentSaved);

    }

    void docEvents_DocumentSaved(Document document)
    {
        //do something here (doesn't reach this)
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, or even a pointer to a simple example project where the DocumentSaved event is working on web site solutions.

EDIT: I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

Look at this (updated):

https://gordon-breuer.de/unknown/2010/08/19/visual-studio-2010-extension-unicode-converter-1-0-with-tutorial.html

It seems that you have to register your add id for handling certain file types.

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.